# Parse Column in Data Frame and Get Max Value

Tags: r, parsing, vector, dataframe

I am a beginner in R and need help to perform the following steps in my `data.frame`:

1) Parse out the non-empty values in each column, and
2) convert the parsed values per column into vectors

[image: Sample Data]

As an example, for Company A what i would like to do is pull the values between "-" and "@" for all non-blank values in that column (i.e. 60 for each non-blank value for Company A). I would then like to create a vector of all the values, e.g. vector = (parseddata1,parseddata2,parseddata3,etc).

The hardest part for me is parsing each column cell by cell and somehow convert the values in each column into a vector.

R object:

```
  Balfour Beatty Rail (uk)-1 Balfour Beatty Rail (uk)-2
1                                                      
2    22 - 4/30/2013 - 30@2.4    27 - 4/30/2013 - 10@2.4
3    17 - 5/31/2013 - 30@2.4    18 - 5/31/2013 - 10@2.4
4    16 - 6/30/2013 - 30@2.4    17 - 6/30/2013 - 10@2.4
5    18 - 7/31/2013 - 30@2.4    19 - 7/31/2013 - 10@2.4
6    19 - 8/31/2013 - 30@2.4    39 - 8/31/2013 - 10@2.4
  Balfour Beatty Utility Solutions-1
1           17 - 3/31/2013 - 210@2.4
2           17 - 4/30/2013 - 210@2.4
3           15 - 5/31/2013 - 420@2.4
4           19 - 6/30/2013 - 420@2.4
5           16 - 7/31/2013 - 420@2.4
6           15 - 8/31/2013 - 420@2.4


dat <-     structure(list(`Balfour Beatty Rail (uk)-1` = c("", "22 - 4/30/2013 - 30@2.4", 
"17 - 5/31/2013 - 30@2.4", "16 - 6/30/2013 - 30@2.4", "18 - 7/31/2013 - 30@2.4", 
"19 - 8/31/2013 - 30@2.4"), `Balfour Beatty Rail (uk)-2` = c("", 
"27 - 4/30/2013 - 10@2.4", "18 - 5/31/2013 - 10@2.4", "17 - 6/30/2013 - 10@2.4", 
"19 - 7/31/2013 - 10@2.4", "39 - 8/31/2013 - 10@2.4"), `Balfour Beatty Utility Solutions-1` = c("17 - 3/31/2013 - 210@2.4", 
"17 - 4/30/2013 - 210@2.4", "15 - 5/31/2013 - 420@2.4", "19 - 6/30/2013 - 420@2.4", 
"16 - 7/31/2013 - 420@2.4", "15 - 8/31/2013 - 420@2.4")), .Names = c("Balfour Beatty Rail (uk)-1", 
"Balfour Beatty Rail (uk)-2", "Balfour Beatty Utility Solutions-1"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please share `dput(head(my_data, 18))` where `my_data` is your data frame. (If this isn't a data frame in R yet, then you need to tell us what it is).

Comment: Hey Gregor. What is the purpose behind sharing the dput? It is very very long and I don't see how it would be of help to you.

Comment: If you use `dput`, we can copy/paste it into R and get the exact same data structure, with the same column classes and everything. We'll have an exact copy of your data object. Then we call all work and test code on your data. About the only way to get the image you posted into R would be to type it in by hand---and even then it's not clear if your columns are factors or characters, if there are strange encodings...

Comment: Just post the output from the first 20 lines. It cannot be any longer that the picture  you have posted. Those pictures are completely useless in building an R object for testing.

Comment: structure(list(`Balfour Beatty Rail (uk)-1` = c("", "22 - 4/30/2013 - 30@2.4", 
"17 - 5/31/2013 - 30@2.4", "16 - 6/30/2013 - 30@2.4", "18 - 7/31/2013 - 30@2.4", 
"19 - 8/31/2013 - 30@2.4"), `Balfour Beatty Rail (uk)-2` = c("", 
"27 - 4/30/2013 - 10@2.4", "18 - 5/31/2013 - 10@2.4", "17 - 6/30/2013 - 10@2.4", 
"19 - 7/31/2013 - 10@2.4", "39 - 8/31/2013 - 10@2.4"), `Balfour Beatty Utility Solutions-1` = c("17 - 3/31/2013 - 210@2.4",

Comment: "17 - 4/30/2013 - 210@2.4", "15 - 5/31/2013 - 420@2.4", "19 - 6/30/2013 - 420@2.4", 
"16 - 7/31/2013 - 420@2.4", "15 - 8/31/2013 - 420@2.4")), .Names = c("Balfour Beatty Rail (uk)-1", 
"Balfour Beatty Rail (uk)-2", "Balfour Beatty Utility Solutions-1"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: i had to break the output into two pieces since it was too long. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You _should_ have edited your question rather than entering data in comments. Notice that he column names appears as code when in the original they are flanked by backticks because of the SO formatting defaults.

Comment: WHat do you mean "cell by cell"? It looks like you are doing the same thing in each cell so you would just do the operation once.

Comment: What happens when there is a two digit month? Also is there always a white space before the number you want, and if so it is at `" "`?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need pattern matching to pull out the numbers you want, then you need to apply this pattern to each column of your data frame. The code below uses a Regular Expression, or regex, for pattern matching, then uses `sapply` to apply that pattern to each column of the data.

Here's how the code below works:

1) `gsub` does string substitution. In this case, we'll identify the numbers you want, return those, and get rid of everything else.

2) This is the regex pattern: `".*- ([0-9]*)@.*"`. It says look for any sequence of characters `.*`, followed by `-`, followed by a single space, followed by any number of digits `[0-9]*`, followed by `@`, followed by any sequence of characters `.*`. The parentheses `([0-9]*)` "capture" what's inside. That's what we want to keep. The `\\1` tells `gsub` to return what's inside this capture group.

3) `gsub` returns character strings. `as.numeric` converts the output to numeric.

4) `sapply` runs a function (in this case the "anonymous" function that extracts numbers from your character data) on each column in the data frame `dat`.

```
datParsed = sapply(dat, function(col) {
  as.numeric(gsub(".* - ([0-9]*)@.*", "\\1", col))
}) 

     Balfour Beatty Rail (uk)-1 Balfour Beatty Rail (uk)-2 Balfour Beatty Utility Solutions-1
[1,]                         NA                         NA                                210
[2,]                         30                         10                                210
[3,]                         30                         10                                420
[4,]                         30                         10                                420
[5,]                         30                         10                                420
[6,]                         30                         10                                420
```

To turn the above output into a single vector of numbers, you can just do `as.vector(datParsed)`.

Note that the code above will work properly on your whole data frame only if the numbers you want always follow `-` (plus a space) and always precede `@`. If the pattern can vary, or if other parts of the string can match this pattern, then a more general regex will be necessary.